# Range Defined by Cells() Gives Error when Adding Border

Tags: excel, vba, border

I am trying to add borders to a certain range in excel. Because I eventually want to use this code in a For loop, I want to define the Range using Cells().

This code does not work:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 3)).Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
.LineStyle = xlContinuous
.Weight = xlThin
.ColorIndex = 1
End With
```

But this code (that refers to the same exact range) does not:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("A1:C1").Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
.LineStyle = xlContinuous
.Weight = xlThin
.ColorIndex = 1
End With
```

What is going on here?

The error I get is

> "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error".

Comment: You need to qualify which `Worksheet` the `Cells` are on, otherwise there's an implicit `ActiveSheet` here. When the "Data" sheet is not active, this throws an error.

Comment: I would make your `With` block refer to the sheet. Then you can just qualify all downstream objects (ranges and cells) with block